# Como fazer um sorted por uma coluna específica de csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tenho um arquivo .csv e preciso fazer um sorted por uma coluna específica (coluna 'salario') e listar pela coluna 'nome' os 10 maiores salários sem utilizar PANDAS.
Podem me ajudar? Desde já agradeço.

```
   lista_top_ten = {} 
    reader = csv.DictReader(arquivo.csv)

    for linha in reader:
        for chave, valor in linha.items():
            try:
                lista_top_ten[chave].append(valor)
            except KeyError:
                lista_top_ten[chave] = [valor]


    sort_top_ten = sorted( reader, reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter('salario'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo com json mas é a mesma ideia com arquivos csv. Pode fazer algo desta forma:

```
def ordenarSalario(value):
  return value['salario']

def os10MaioresSalarios():
    result = []
    data = json.loads(json_api)
    data.sort(reverse=True, key=ordenarSalario)
    for pessoa in data[:10]: 
      result.append(pessoa["nome"])
    return result
```